# Dart layout convention regarding internationalization bundles

Tags: dart

Is there a recommended best practice regarding the darts folder layout convention regarding internationalization bundles and folder within the dart project hierarchy?

Comment: No best practice that I know of, but what would you think it should be? Or: what convention would you use in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You may use  intl library.

Open your pubspec.yaml file and add "intl : any" (without double quote). And save or run pub install.

You may read intl library API reference at http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/intl.html

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. The way the Intl library works for messages is that it generates them into separate libraries. Right now they're all loaded, but once lazy loading works a bit better we expect to use that to load only the ones you need. If they're in libraries, then it doesn't really matter where the code is as long as it's visible. If you're using some other mechanism, then whatever the layout convention is for that system is probably what to follow.